# How does the apt-get purge command work?

Tags: apt, software-installation, uninstall, purge

How does 'it' (ie. `purge`) know where the dependencies and configuration files are located?

How does `purge` find out that a particular piece of software created a certain file?

Is there some sort of configuration file that records the creation of all files by programs, so that `purge` can access the records and match up the files to the program during removal?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I do know that DEBs tend to just have files inside under paths that match paths on the computer. It's probable `purge` looks inside the DEB and deletes all matching files on the computer. If the DEB doesn't have the config files by default, `purge` won't find them. I have had times where using `purge` doesn't actually remove all configs

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't remove files *created by* a particular piece of software, just the ones *installed by* the package (which are listed in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/package.conffiles`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are such files. In particular, `*.list`, `*.postrm` , and `*.conffiles`, which are all stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` directory.

The `.postrm` files are post-remove scripts, that run after a package is removed. Those scripts are responsibility of the package maintainers, and each script is tailored to the specific package. If you examine  `/var/lib/dpkg/info/usb-modeswitch-data.postrm` for example , you will see something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Automatically added by dh_installdeb
dpkg-maintscript-helper rm_conffile "/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/230d:0001" 20101222-3 -- "$@"
# End automatically added section
```

There's also `*.list` and `*.conffiles` files, which are basically lists. `gnome-terminal.list`, for example, will list all files and directories created when `gnome-terminal` was installed. The `*.list` files are very useful for determining what installed what.  `*.conffiles` list all the config files for a package. For instance, while `xterm.list` gives *all* the files , `xterm.conffiles* gives only conffiles. In other words, the contents of conffile will also be present in list file.

```
$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/xterm.conffiles                                       
/etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm
/etc/X11/app-defaults/KOI8RXTerm-color
/etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm-color
/etc/X11/app-defaults/UXTerm-color
/etc/X11/app-defaults/UXTerm
/etc/X11/app-defaults/KOI8RXTerm
```

I don't quite know how   `*.conffiles` work. My assumption is that the post-removal scripts take priority, and `apt-get` just uses those `*.conffiles` to double check that files listed there were removed.

As @A.B. properly reminded me, there are also `*.prerm` files, some of which do remove the .conf files, but not necessarily, for instance the one for `xpdf` app was removing the files in `/etc/xpdf/includes` directory

Comment: You forgot the prerm-files =)

Comment: @A.B. thank you for the reminder, #included<update.h> :)