# Command to get the list of files deleted by apt purge but not by apt remove?

Tags: apt

I would like to know in advance which files would be deleted if I ran `apt purge <pkg>` and that would not be deleted by running the `apt remove <pkg>` command.

Is there some CLI voodoo better that running both command with -s and comparing the results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the apt-get purge command work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705006/how-does-the-apt-get-purge-command-work)

Comment: I am looking for some command to know which files are removed by purge but not by remove. This is not the same question as the potential dup. I have edited my text to try to make it more clear.

Comment: That is exactly what the answer suggested by @N0rbert tells you - look into the appropriate files (eg using `cat` or `less`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only difference between remove and purge are the config files and only the config files (still not 100% sure about that), this should answer my question:

`dpkg-query --showformat='${Conffiles}\n' --show <package>`

Am I wrong?